# Server 2012 R2 - Sharing 'cluster shared volume' .VHDX hard drives between two VMs, are they supposed to not live update?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, failovercluster, vhdx

I have a .VHDX volume that's a cluster shared volume in a Server 2012 R2 failover cluster. I'm able to share the hard drive between two VMs. If I create a folder on VM2, it doesn't show in VM1 in the hard drive unless I reboot that machine or go into disk management > rescan disks > import disk. Is this normal behavior?

One thing of note I found on TechNet's site was this:

> When you use shared VHDX with local block storage, synchronization must occur for shared VHDX file access. If the virtual machines are running on different nodes, this involves network redirection for the synchronization activity. If you have fast block connectivity combined with slow intra-cluster network communication, this synchronization activity results in I/O variance (either redirected or direct) based on the node. This happens on a per file basis. (The entire CSV is not in redirected mode.) To increase performance, we recommend that you scale the intra-cluster network.
>
> Be aware that this is not a consideration when you use file-based
>   storage. When you use a compute layer of file-based storage over SMB
>   together with a remote Scale-Out File Server (SOFS), this shared file
>   access orchestration is performed by the SOFS. With a SOFS, SMB
>   sessions are transitioned to optimize file access. The SMB sessions
>   co-exist on the same node that performs the synchronization. As a
>   result, there is no network communication.

I've used both the VHDX directly as just a VHD in the CSV and as a VHD in an SOFS share in the CSV. Doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Did you install the failover-cluster role within the VMs that share the VHDX?

Comment: Hey Daniel, no I did not, I see it mentioned several times in the documentation but wasn't aware that it also had to be installed in the VMs. So this doesn't work between two VMs that are Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10 right?

Comment: No, it is not supported. Although it may work, file saftey cannot be guaranteed. Check the other question for more information.